# Django redirection to another page not working

Tags: html, django, url

So I'm trying to create a webstore using Django and HTML. To make it short, my problem is that when I press the button "Products" on the navigation bar it gives me an 404 error.
[This is the error it gives me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tz0b.png)

It also gives me errors in the terminal
[The error in the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZoo0.png)

I have been trying to figure out what's wrong for the past hour but nothing seems to be working.
Here's my code;

(The file product.html is located in a folder named "templates")

My views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Item # Skriptist models.py impordib eseme (Item'i) #


def product(request):
    context = {
        "items": Item.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, "product.html", context)

def checkout(request):
    return render(request, "checkout.html")



class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home.html"


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import (
    ItemDetailView,
    checkout,
    HomeView
)
# Skriptist views.py improdib "item_list'i" #

app_name = "core"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
]
```

And finally this is my scripts.html file which has all of the javascript stuff.

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mdb.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Initializations -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Animations initialization
  new WOW().init();

</script>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Nimetu.

Comment: The slug part is missing in the URL. So it is not a valid url pattern.

Comment: path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product/<slug>/'), You mean this? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: no. I mean that on the page where the link to *that* page is, it is missing the slug.

Comment: So in the views.py or in my navigation bar file? (I probably sound so dumb right now but I'm confused)

Comment: @Nimetu You need to set <slug> in the URL from where you are redirecting to that page. I think from navigation bar file or the HTML file where you had called this view

Comment: Hm the slug is for when a product title is clicked so it opens up the details of the product and in the navigation bar file the code is like this
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="product">
            Products</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

So it's looking for the product.html file

Comment: Also I tried it, didn't work @MehaParekh

Comment: Had you set the <slug> field? and what error is coming now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because the URL you are accessing does not match any of the patterns in your urls.py. You are accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/product which is not valid as your pattern has a trailing slash and then the slug, though the definition is also wrong for that.

Your url patterns should be

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('checkout/', checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('product/<slug:slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product'),
]
```

Then you can access URLs such as:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/product-1
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/product-2

If you want http://127.0.0.1:8000/product to work then you need to add a new entry and decide what it should display such as a ListView